# Remove HTML from search.php of my parent theme

Tags: child-theme

I have a child theme of the theme alterna, and in the search.php (among other code) there is this:

```
<div class="entry-left-side span3">
                                        <div class="post-date-type row-fluid">
                                            <div class="post-type"><i class="big-icon-file"></i></div>
                                            <div class="date">
                                                <div class="day"><?php echo get_the_date('d'); ?></div>
                                                <div class="month"><?php echo get_the_date('M'); ?></div>
                                                <div class="year"><?php echo get_the_date('Y'); ?></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

I want to be able to get rid of just that part, so I am thinking on copying the exact search.php to the child theme and get rid of that part.

Is that the correct way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Yup, best way of doing it, always use a child theme to do core edits to a theme so you have a backup incase of issues in future or upgrades.

Comment: Exactly how it should be done. You are on the right track

Comment: But then, if the parent theme is updated, and they change the search.php file, I would be outdated right?

Comment: Yes but it won't break your search file and you only need to then edit the child theme file again if it needs an amendment.